# sending a GET request with payload in Python

Tags: python

I'd like to call the Facebook graph API to query some information about an object.  The GET method is required.  However, for security purposes, I'd like to hide the access token in a payload.  I tested in Graph API Explorer.  It worked.  But I cannot do it using Python code.

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url, data={'access_token' : '0123456789ABCDEF',})
r.text
```

The response is

> {"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,"fbtrace_id":"AQshJ5NFFYMaED92Azgo0AL"}}

I changed `data=` to `json=` and it does not work.

Comment: GET requests don't have bodies (paylods).  You must send the token as a qurey parameter or a header (assuming the server will accept either form).

Comment: @RoadRunner I want to hide the token.  The url begins with https.  Putting the token in the header does not work.  I got the same error.

Comment: @wannik You may try params `params = (
  ('access_token', '{your-user-access-token}'),
);
response = requests.get(url, params=params)`

Comment: @CodeIt Is `params=` put the python dictionary in a query string?

Comment: @wannik Yes, it will.

Comment: If ACCESS_TOKEN is in a query string, then it is not secure.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your URL to URL+parameter
Eg:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Different way:

```
payload = {'access_token': 'ACCESS_TOKEN'}
r = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me', params=payload)
```

If you want to avoid insecureness of exposing access token, You can use [appsecret_proof](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/) along with the parameters. So, spamming becomes impossible.

This simple encryption technique avoids the usage of access token without proof.

> An access token can also be stolen by malicious software on a person's
>   computer or a man in the middle attack
>
> You can prevent this by adding the appsecret_proof parameter to every
>   API call from a server and enabling the setting to require proof on
>   all calls

.

Comment: Your method works.  But I don't want to put the token in the URL.

Comment: API accepts only this format. What you mean by don't want to put?

Comment: Is `params=` put the python dictionary in a query string?

Comment: requests.get(url, params={key: value}, args)

Comment: If `params` is in a query string, then it is not secure.

Comment: I edited answer. You can make things in a way that attacker cannot do anything from acquired access token. It is necessary to have access token in query string in FB API.